# Residual modeling for mixed models: Any other package than nlme?

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

Aside from R function `nlme::lme()`, I'm wondering how else I can model the Level-1 residual variance-covariance structure?

**ps.** My search showed I could possibly use `glmmTMB` package but it seems it is not about Level-1 residuals but random-effects themselves (*see below code*).

```
glmmTMB::glmmTMB(y ~ times + ar1(times | subjects), data = data) ## DON'T RUN

nlme::lme    (y ~ times, random = ~ times | subjects,
     correlation = corAR1(), data = data) ## DON'T RUN
```

Comment: "is there a package that?" is off-topic for SO, but "how can I ... ?" is not (even if the answer is "try package XXX")

Comment: `lme4` package?? check [here](http://www.dwoll.de/rexrepos/posts/anovaMixed.html)

Comment: More context would also help, i.e. is there a particular reason that `lme` won't work for you? Or is this purely curiosity-driven?

Comment: it does. you do use `lme4` package for level1 residuals

Comment: The difference is due to the different sigma used. in the second example, use sigma_long

Comment: probably check https://www.lcampanelli.org/mixed-effects-modeling-lme4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glmmTMB` can effectively be used to model level-1 residuals, by adding an observation-level random effect to the model (and if necessary suppressing the level-1 variance via `dispformula ~ 0`.  For example, comparing the same fit in `lme` and `glmmTMB`:

```
library(glmmTMB)
library(nlme)

data("sleepstudy" ,package="lme4")
ss <- sleepstudy
ss$times <- factor(ss$Days)  ## needed for glmmTMB
```

I initially tried with `random = ~Days|Subject` but neither `lme` nor `glmmTMB` were happy (overfitted):

```
lme1 <- lme(Reaction ~ Days, random = ~1|Subject,
            correlation=corAR1(form=~Days|Subject), data=ss)

m1 <- glmmTMB(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject) +
                  ar1(times + 0 | Subject),
              dispformula=~0,
              data=ss,
              REML=TRUE,
              start=list(theta=c(4,4,1)))
```

Unfortunately, in order to get a good answer with `glmmTMB` I did have to tweak the starting values ...

Comment: Many many thanks, Ben! It was out of curiosity; knowing that `glmmTMB` allows random-effects var-covar modeling but not level-1 residual modeling sounded a bit strange to me. I also wanted to know if there is any kind of link between `glmmTMB` and `lme()` which your code, very clearly shows!